# start rails from init.d service script and loads the correct version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to start `rails` server in production mode after installing, migrating and running some scripts in order for this script to be attached as pipeline deploy script.

**The problem is that the same script doesn't work as service mode.**

`ubuntu@ip-x-y-z-w:~/backend.rails.com$ sudo vim /etc/init.d/rails-start-backend`

```
#! /bin/sh
# Start/stop the rails server daemon.
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rails server start
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DESC="rails daemon"
NAME=rails
DAEMON=/home/ubuntu/backend.rails.com/gitlab-ci.sh
PIDFILE=/var/run/rails.pid

test -f $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions


case "$1" in

start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting rails"
        /home/ubuntu/backend.rails.com/gitlab-ci.sh > /home/ubuntu/backend.rails.com/log/start_script.log
        start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON $EXTRA_OPTS
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
stop)   log_daemon_msg "Stopping rails" "rails"
        sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
        killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && [ -e "$PIDFILE" ] && rm -f $PIDFILE
        log_end_msg $RETVAL
        ;;

restart) log_daemon_msg "Restarting " "rails"
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
reload|force-reload) log_daemon_msg "Reloading rails" "rails"
        # rails reloads automatically
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
*)      log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/rails {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}"
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and thats my `gitlab-ci.sh` script

```
cd /home/ubuntu/backend.rails.com
sudo chmod +x gitlab-ci.sh 
rm config/master.key
rm config/credentials.yml.enc
echo "credentials"
RAILS_ENV=production EDITOR="mate --wait" rails credentials:edit
export RAILS_ENV=production 
export FRONTEND_BASE_URL=https://www.rails.com 
echo "bundle install"
bundle install
echo "rails db:migrate"
bundle exec rails db:migrate
echo "rails rake application:initialize"
bundle exec rake application:initialize
echo "kill"
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
echo "start"
rails s &
```

The problem comes when I restarted the `sudo service rails-start-backend restart` service. It seems that in that context, all bundle, rails and ruby versions and settings are not the same as when I execute the same script manually in ssh.

The errors I get are:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks2.6’: No such file or directory
bundle: not found
```

here's my PATH when ssh-logged

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

and then when the script is executed as service

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Are you trying to start a 2nd instance of rails before killing the first one?

Comment: it should first kill the old one and then starts a new one. 
`echo "kill" &&
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000) &&
echo "start" &&
rails s &`
but I guess the problem is not there. it's a ruby version prolem. the same script works if executed manually while logged as ssh.

Comment: I think setting `PATH` in your script is part of the problem.

Comment: yes. see PATH output.

Answer (score 0):

It works after setting the right paths to the right variables (using `2.6.5` ruby version)

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:$PATH
export GEM_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global:$GEM_PATH
source .bash_profile
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```